# file permission: one user with multiple permission types

Tags: permissions, file-shares

The situation I thought of is, that one user get's two links with different types of permission for the same file (didn't find a satisfying answer yet):

- **Link A:** read-only
- **Link B:** full access

Now if the user opens the file with **Link A**, what is he able to do?

- just **view** the file
  or
- **edit it** because the 2nd permission is stronger?

Comment: Do you create sharing links in SPO? Are the users inside or outside of your organization? Why do you not just try it out? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, when sharing links are created, permissions along with other information are stored in a hidden SharePoint List called **Sharing Links**.
For example, if link is shared with read permission, **RoleDefinitionId 1073741826**, and with editing, **RoleDefinitionId 1073741827**, are stored in the list. So, the permission of document defined in the shared link is retrieved from this list when the link is accessed.

Assuming the user receiving the link does not have any other permissions given directly to the site/library, the user will have the permission as defined during creation of the respective link, that is, in this case, **Link A** will have **Read Only** and **Link B** will have **full access** regardless the order of accessing the links.

You can read more on **Sharing Links** [here](https://www.netwoven.com/2020/06/04/inside-the-sharing-links-when-sharing-a-document-in-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive/)

For **RoleDefinitionId**, [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-sharepoint-role-definition-ids/)